# Is there an option in Play Framework (1.2.4) to always do redirects as HTTPS?

Tags: redirect, https, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have not been able to find a way to do this. We need to do a 302 redirect from http://www.doortodoororganics.com to https://www.doortodoororganics.com/landing. The way we are doing it now redirects to http://www.doortodoororganics.com/landing, and then Apache does the redirect to https. I realize I could change it in the Controller, but we have several places in the code where we do redirects, and I would much rather set it once so that *all* redirects go to HTTPS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Write a Base Controller and have a Before Interceptor which can set the

> play.mvc.Http.Request.secure

property to **true** always.

The Play framework checks this property before redirecting. If true it does a https redirection.

Comment: It's better to put the logic into the http front-end server (e.g. nginx) configuration that your play-app stay neutral to environment setting

Answer (score 0):

Use a front http server that acts as a proxy in front of your play application. This is trivially done using apache httpd : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html It could also be done in any other http server such as nginx...